# Django form, Validate field dynamically

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm trying to dynamically validate a field by getting the max value from a related table.
The **course** model has a field called **years** which is the duration. So when choosing a particular **course** the value of the **year** field should be between 1 and the duration of the course.

Update: Right now it returns an error **int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Course'**.

## forms.py

```
class SelectCourseYear(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['course', 'year']

    def clean_year(self):
        course = self.cleaned_data.get('course')
        year = self.cleaned_data.get('year')
        course_years = Course.objects.get(pk=course).years
        if ((year <= 0) and (year > course_years)):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Error. Check year of studies.')
        return course
```

Comment: `def clean_year(self): ... return course` : `clean_year` should return `year`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes you're right! But still I'm getting that error about 'Course'.

Comment: Do this: After `course_years = Course.objects.get(pk=course).years` insert the line `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` and resubmit your form. In the window running the test server you should get `(pdb)` prompt. Type `course_years` at that prompt and tell me the value.

Comment: Tried it but the process doesn't stop. It continues until the error page.(I have used pdb just once, and it was stopping the process so I was able to type next to `(pdb)`).

Comment: Err, that would seem to indicate `clean_year` isn't getting called. Are you sure? (Don't put it under the `if` statement.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I double checked it. It's just after the line you said. You can check it at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Zv36HWLQ)

Comment: How were you calling `clean_year` before when you got the error? Why is it not getting called now? And just to double-check you do have a terminal open and running somewhere that's running the dev server?

Comment: Ok I managed to use pdb. When I type `course_years`` I'm getting **3L**. @Two-BitAlchemist (**Update**: The years of the course I selected is **3**)

Comment: What line are you getting that error on? Do you have it posted already?

Comment: I'm getting "3L" after line `-> if (year <= 0) or (year > course_years):`. The form is not submitting since we added the pdb.

Comment: So I think it should be `3` and NOT `3L` right?

Comment: `int(3L)` does not raise a `ValueError`. Where are you getting the `ValueError`?

Comment: Sorry but i'm a bit confused. What do you mean?

Comment: From the django error:
course......<Course: Computer Science, BSc (Hons)>
self......<membership.forms.SelectCourseYear object at 0x102e3b2d0>
year......4

So I guess course should be an id in order for the line below to work?
`course_years = Course.objects.get(id=course).years`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
(year <= 0) or (year > course_years)
```

Comment: Yes you're right. But still I'm getting an error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Course'`.

Comment: I would be tempted to do the following and then print out the returned object using dir(): course_lkup = Course.objects.get(pk=course)

Comment: Can you explain that? Is this like `course_years = Course.objects.get(pk=course).years`?

Comment: You'll need to learn how to debug python. One way is to print out the methods/properties of objects using dir(). For example: course_lkup = Course.objects.get(pk=course) and then print out the course_lkup object using print dir(course_lkup). Learn how to use type, str, and dir - see http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html.